# TCP Server Windows 8 XAML Application in C#

Tags: c#, windows-8, tcp, tcplistener, tcpserver

I recently developed a TCP Client-Server application using WPF and C# for Windows Desktop.
Now, I'm thinking to port it to Windows 8 Metro App.

But, it seems that System.Net.Sockets namespace in not present in the SDK for Metro Apps.
(So I cannot use TcpListener, TcpClient, etc)
I could not find a working example, either.

Is it possible to create a TCP-IP Server as a Windows 8 Metro App (using some different approach)?
Are there any third-party libraries (free and open-source, preferably) available to accomplish this?

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR226882 ?

Comment: Did it work? Pls mark my Answer if it's right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's recommended to use [StreamSocket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocket.aspx) class instead.

Here is an [Example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/StreamSocket-Sample-8c573931) from MSDN.

---

A socket provides send and receive over TCP and a **StreamSocketListener** will listen for incoming TCP connections.

Here is my Idea:

First we need a Instance of StreamSocketListener.

```
private StreamSocketListener _listener = new StreamSocketListener();
```

Then start the listener wire up a connection received event handler and bind the service name.

```
_listener.ConnectionReceived += listenerConnectionReceived;
await _listener.BindServiceNameAsync("localServiceName");
```

> If the *localServiceName* parameter is an empty string, then the system
>   will select the local TCP port on which to bind. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh701492)

Now we have to recive the Connection:

```
        void listenerConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Recive connection from {0}", args.Socket.Information.RemoteHostName.DisplayName));
        }
```

---

BTW: I did a lot of research for this and haven't time left  (and a Windows 8 METRO Development Environment) to prof my ideas. Hope i get soon to this. It really bugs me. (German/English) ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and sorry for the late response! :-)


I tried using StreamSocket class but I could not use it to create a TCP socket listener (or server). I successfully created a TCP Client using this class, however. Can you help me find a code sample to create a TCP Server using the StreamSocket class?

Comment: @ShrayanshSharma Did some change.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked! But, how do I read the content (string) sent from the Client? I want to save it in a string.

Comment: Yay! I managed to read the content sent by the cient.

Thanks a lot for your help! :-)